# How to implement full screen scrollable in this code android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**I have a column where I have multiple `LazyVerticalGrid` components, and I want to implement full-screen scrollability in this code. The current code is not working as expected. When I run this code, the last `LazyVerticalGrid` is scrollable but it remains fixed in its position. How can I implement full-screen scrollability in this code? attach my full code**

i want like this image

````
fun MoreScreen(
    moreMenusTopSection: ArrayList<MoreMenus>?,
    onItemCallback: (menus: Menus?, onDismiss: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
      
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White)
            ) {
                items(moreMenusTopSection) { item ->
                    Column(
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.white))
                            .padding(start = 13.dp, end = 13.dp, top = 30.dp)
                            .clickable {

                            }
                    ) {
                       
                        CommonText(
                            text = item.name.toString(),
                            fontSize = 13,
                            color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_gray),
                            maxline = 2,
                            textOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White)
            ) {
                items(moreMenusTopSection) { item ->
                    Column(
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.white))
                            .padding(start = 13.dp, end = 13.dp, top = 30.dp)
                            .clickable {

                            }
                    ) {
                        
                        CommonText(
                            text = item.name.toString(),
                            fontSize = 13,
                            color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_gray),
                            maxline = 2,
                            textOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Hts.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use repeat(1) -> Unit inside your parent.

```
Column {
        repeat(1) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
                items(50) {
                    Text(text = "Nested Item 1")
                }
            }

            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
                items(50) {
                    Text(text = "Nested Item 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If your nested items are dynamic then use a parent LazyColumn() which is recommended.

```
LazyColumn {
        item(1) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
                items(50) {
                    Text(text = "Nested Item 1")
                }
            }

            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
                items(50) {
                    Text(text = "Nested Item 2")
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: the second one is bad. you should not put two vertically scrolling  items in same direction under a scrollview. Its the same with recyclerview. Use One parent LazyColumn and add child to it

Comment: I agree with you but there are a few scenarios where you might need this.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad design to have two independent scrollable layouts inside column to achieve the desired functionality, you could still achieve single scroll by manipulating scroll state but I would recommend to use single `LazyVerticalGrid` with multiple `items` and get rid of `Column`

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White)
    ) {
         items(moreMenusTopSection) { item -> //first section }
         items(moreMenusTopSection) { item -> //second section}
                    
    }
}
```

Comment: first section have header title and also second section have header title .i want when second section scroll from bottom to top also first section will be scroll like nested scroll

Comment: Having them in a single parent scroll, would give the desired result! you could also have two headers inside single grid